# "maxConcurrentRequests" is not working in dedicated ASP for azure function

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have Azure function in V4. and I have host.json as it is mentioned that maxConcurrentRequests is 10 but at the time of execution azure function ignores this setting. I checked on the internet and found that it was a bug in azure function V3 so I updated my version to 4, but still, i am not able to control maxConcurrentRequest.

And the strange thing is that same code is working fine in consumption plan. because in consumption plan default value for maxConcurrentRequest is 100. and in ASP  it is unbounded. and in my case even if I mentioned maxConcurrentRequest is 10 but still it is taking default value.

[image]

Lots of Thanks for help(in Advance).

Comment: If you're using the `Dedicated ASP`, then try setting the `maxConcurrentRequests` to `-1` as it is unbounded and check once!

Comment: but I don't want unbounded value. I want it only 10 that's why I made maxConcurrentRequests= 10, but somehow the azure function ignores this setting and executes with the default value(-1) mean unbounded.

Comment: According to [MS Doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/functions-host-json-http.md), The default for Azure Functions version 2.x+ in a dedicated plan is unbounded (-1).

Comment: yes, we know that the default value is -1, but we are trying to change it lower and are unable to do that. somehow it is still taking default value.

Comment: @vishnuprajapati did you able to set the value?

Comment: @kyo no, I wasn't able to.